# Meteor: Handling Instagram Realtime API Requests via callback-Url with iron-router

Tags: meteor, instagram, iron-router

I'm trying to use the Instagram Realtime API with a Meteor app. Basically you can subscribe to a tag get latest posts.

So I need to setup a callback URL and send a post request with my callbackurl, the object & fields that I want to subscribe and a verify string. A Instagram server is sending a get request with my verify string and a random string (challenge) and the Meteor server has to respond to this with the challenge string.

I'm getting the following error serverside:

```
error_message: 'Challenge verification failed. Sent "b58b60bb367d40148defa4e6240b2dc2", received "<!DOCTYPE> html..."..etc
```

In order to verify the subscription, your server must respond to the GET request with the **hub.challenge** parameter only.

How do I respond to instagram API with the **hub.challenge** parameter.

Resources:
http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#

Comment: Are you using iron-router? [Server side routes](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#server-side-routing) may help.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy yes..

Comment: Did the server-side routes help then?

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy Nopes. maybe i am doing it the wrong way.. and not able to figure it out whats wrong.
I am able to the same thing in nodejs but not in meteor.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some sample code, or a link to your repo (if the code is in a public repo)